# Como fazer um degradê nas extremidades de uma linha, com CSS?

Tags: html, css

Provavelmente essa pode ser uma pergunta repetida, mas como não sei o nome do efeito não consigo achar nada sobre ele, o efeito que quero fazer na borda é exatamente igual ao da imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Como posso fazer esse efeito?
- Qual o nome dele?

Comment: Você quer dizer essa linha com as pontas finas, um pouco degradê?

Comment: Sim, nas pontas fininho sumindo aos poucos, e no meio na espessura normal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu faria uma `div` com tamanho fixo, deixando o `backgound` gradiente linear:

**HTML**

```
<div class="linha"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.linha { 
    margin: 10px 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: black;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(white), to(white), color-stop(50%, black));
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```css
.linha {
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(white), to(white), color-stop(50%, black));
}
```

```html
<div class="linha"></div>
```

Comment: Não é nas bordas como imaginei, mas me serviu muito bem , obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Complementando, eu faria assim meu `hr`:

```css
hr{
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, black, transparent);
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Acredito ser mais simples esta solução, agora é só escolher a cor desejada e colocar onde esta o `black`

Comment: +1 ambas as soluções estão no caminho certo, mas essa me parece mais padrão.